# Screenshot for Protractor Cucumber HTML report

Tags: protractor

I want to take separate screenshot for all the data rows (examples) when they fail in a scenario outline.

I am using the below code to take it but it captures same screenshot for all the failed examples as it overwrites the previous screenshots.

Please tell me how to do it.

Sample Cucumber Feature:

Scenario Outline :

Given XXXXX "Parameter 1" and "Parameter 2"

When XXXX

Then XXXXX

Examples:

|Parameter 1| Parameter 2|

|A|B| --- This got failed

|C|D|

|E|F| -- This got failed

I want to have separate screenshot for data row 1 and 3.

```
if (scenario.isFailed()) {
browser.takeScreenshot()
  .then(function(base64png) {
    var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64png, 'base64').toString('binary');
    scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
    callback();
}, function(err) {
  callback(err);
});
```

}

Comment: You might want to have a look at [Serenity/JS](http://serenity-js.org), which can compliment your current Protractor/Cucumber setup to take the screenshots automatically - [see this answer for instructions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34821016/is-there-a-protractor-reporting-tool-that-works-with-a-cucumber-framework/42598696#42598696)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use. Notice that as of like cucumberjs 1.2.0 you no longer do the '.toString('binary') on the buffer.

```
    this.After(function(scenario, callback) {
        browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(base64png) {
            var decodedImage = new Buffer(base64png, 'base64');
            scenario.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png', function (error) {
                callback(error);
            });
        }, function(err) {
            callback(err);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
defineSupportCode(({After}) => {
After(function(scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        var attach = this.attach; 
            return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function(png) {
        var decodedImage = new Buffer(png, "base64");
            return attach(decodedImage, "image/png");
        });
        }
    });
});
```