# Is there a Protractor Reporting Tool that works with a cucumber framework?

Tags: automated-tests, protractor

Using protractor with cucumber and need a plug in or tool (free if possible) that will create a user friendly test report or at least a file that a test report can be generated from.   Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is to compliment your current setup with the free and open-source [Serenity/JS](http://serenity-js.org/).

Serenity/JS is a next generation acceptance testing library, but in the most basic scenario, it can also act as an integration layer between Protractor and Cucumber.

This enables you to:

- Run your tests in parallel and still get the aggregated, user-friendly test reports.
- Enhance your test reports with screenshots of your app's UI without any additional plugins.
- Fix some common problems related to Cucumber/WebDriver ControlFlow synchronisation and inaccurate reporting with just a single config change.
- Try the [Screenplay Pattern](http://serenity-js.org/design/screenplay-pattern.html) in some part of your project while keeping your other tests working as they used to. This way you minimise the risk of disrupting the work of your team while improving your tool set.

The below setup instructions are explained in detail in [the manual](http://serenity-js.org/overview/retrofitting.html), and the reports you'll get will look like this:

[image]

## Setup

Install the [serenity-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serenity-js) module from the npm and save it as a development dependency:

```
npm install serenity-js --save-dev
```

With the serenity-js module installed, you can update your Protractor configuration file to include:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'), 
    // ...
}
```

If you're currently using the `protractor-cucumber-framework`, you can simply replace it with `serenity-js`.

## Report generation

Serenity/JS produces test execution reports in `json` format and to convert them to `html` you'll need `serenity-cli` (which is a node.js wrapper around the [Serenity BDD](http://serenity-bdd.info/#/) CLI, which in turn is a Java program and you'll need the [Java Runtime Environment 7](https://java.com/en/download/) or newer to run it).

Install `serenity-cli` and save it as a development dependency:

```
npm install serenity-cli --save-dev
```

Next, add the following [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to your `package.json` file:

```
 "scripts": {
    "prereport": "serenity update",
    "report":  "serenity run",

    // other scripts ...
  },
```

With the above setup complete running your protractor tests will produce test reports in the `json` format together with screenshots under `target/site/serenity`, and running `npm run report` will process those intermediary reports and produce the user-friendly HTML version you're after.

Hope this helps,

Jan

Comment: I get  E/launcher - Error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/etc/cups/ssl'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:952:18)
    at GlobSync._readdir (/home/ali/node_modules/cucumber/node_modules/glob/sync.js:288:41)
[18:15:41] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100,Do you have any instructions?

Comment: Hey Ali, if you think think this is related to Serenity/JS could you please submit a ticket on github? Thanks! github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js

Comment: @JanMolak my exports.config already have framework: 'jasmine'. Can I use serenity reports with protractor-jasmine framework?? If yes, how can I do that in my protractot-conf.js file?

Comment: Hi there, at the moment Serenity/JS supports Cucumber and Mocha as those libraries provide better support for asynchronous tests and offer easier integration with custom reporters than Jasmine. Jasmine could be supported as well and I'm open to PRs if anyone is interested.

Comment: Thanks for confirming :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the cucumberjs-allure-reporter package and it provides a pretty extensive reporting capability. I've been able to create hooks that take screen shots, capture browser logs and network traffic reports after each step allowing me to track quite a bit of information for each test.

Instructions for setting it up is a bit vague, but once you find all of the info, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

you can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber-html-reporter, which integrates well with the Protractor

e.g. [HTML Preview of Report with Pie Charts](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/gkushang/cucumber-html-reporter/blob/develop/samples/html_reports/cucumber_report_bootstrap.html)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DBNq.png)

Comment: Please elaborate. A link  is not consider as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/igniteram/protractor-cucumber-allure

Use the above repo. It has two different html reports within it. you can also use the hooks to screenshot when there is a failure. I tried it and it works like a charm.